# ¿Por qué la API de Google Analytics me devuelve varias filas si es la misma URL? ¿Cómo indicarle que envíe el total de visitas en una sola fila?

Tags: php, google-analytics

Estoy trabajando con la API de Google Analytics en PHP.

Ahora mismo estoy preparando un código para mostrar el número de visitas de cada página, filtrando por la URL actual.

Lo que me ha sorprendido es que para una misma URL la API me devuelve varias filas de resultados, por ejemplo, para la URL: `homilias-ciclo-b_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo/` puedo obtener este resultado:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Homilías Domingo 03 Tiempo de Cuaresma (B) Templo | deiverbum.org
            [1] => /homilias-ciclo-b_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo/
            [2] => 411
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Homilías Domingo III Tiempo de Cuaresma (Ciclo B) | deiverbum.org
            [1] => /homilias-ciclo-b_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo/
            [2] => 339
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => No se encontró la página
            [1] => /homilias-ciclo-b_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo/
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

Efectivamente, la URL tiene un total de `411+339+2` visitas, o sea, **`752`visitas**. Evidentemente, GA diferencia las visitas por el título, pero no sé por qué lo hace así si yo estoy filtrando por la URL de esta manera `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$requestUri`, como se podrá ver en el código de más abajo.

La función que me devuelve el array indicado más arriba es esta:

```
function getTotalViews($profileId,$analytics) {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $optParams = array(
        'max-results' => 5,
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$requestUri,
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'start-index'=>1,
    );

    $res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:' . $profileId,
        '2012-01-01',
        'today',
        'ga:pageviews',
        $optParams);

    $rows=$res["rows"]; 
    return $rows;
}
```

**¿Cómo indicar a la API que me de un sólo resultado basado en `$requestUri` con todas las visitas que ha recibido esa página, independientemente del título?**

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre si quitas `ga:pageTitle` de la lista en `dimensions`?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro ha funcionado con tu sugerencia, de hecho, tenía varias cosas de más... La función ha quedado así y me obtiene justo el total de visitas de la página en una sola fila: `function getTotalViews($profileId,$analytics) {
 $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $optParams = array(
  'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$requestUri);
 $res= $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $profileId,
  '2012-01-01',
  'today',
  'ga:pageviews',
  $optParams);
 $rows=$res["rows"]; 
 return $rows[0][0];
}`. Agradecería que escribas una respuesta para dar el asunto por solucionado. Gracia.

Comment: Perfecto. Voy a ver si encuentro documentación oficial que dé soporte a eso y pongo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [documentación de la API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions) se indica que las métricas se pueden desglosar por criterios comunes, algo así como agrupar los datos por los que se van a obtener los valores (parecido a  un `group by` en SQL).

Ahora mismo en los parámetros que le pasas a la petición estás indicando dos dimensiones (`ga:pageTitle` y `ga:pagePath`) y por eso recibes los datos divididos por título de la página (que varía) y por ruta de la página (que es común como indicas en los filtros).

Si no quieres que los datos se *rompan* por título de página, sino sólo por la ruta de la página, entonces deberías quitar `ga:pageTitle` de las dimensiones:

```
$optParams = array(
    'max-results' => 5,
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
    'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$requestUri,
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
    'start-index'=>1,
);
```

Y entonces, [como indicas en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143914/por-qu%C3%A9-la-api-de-google-analytics-me-devuelve-varias-filas-si-es-la-misma-url?noredirect=1#comment269768_143914), podrías simplificar la lista de parámetros opcionales, porque ya no harían falta algunos de ellos (p.e. `max-results`, `start-index` o `sort` ya no tendrían sentido porque sólo se va a devolver un valor).

La consulta final quedaría entonces así, dentro de una función:

```
function getTotalViews($profileId,$analytics) 
{ 
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $optParams = array  ( 
                            'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$requestUri
                        ); 
    $res= $analytics->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $profileId, '2012-01-01', 'today', 'ga:pageviews', $optParams); $rows=$res["rows"]; 
    return $rows[0][0]; 
}
```

> **NOTA:** Aunque finalmente opté por guardar un total de visitas en una tabla de la base de datos el cual se actualiza cada cierto tiempo
>   (aproximadamente cada 4 horas). Así muestro el total de visitas
>   extraído de mi tabla y no de Google Analytics directamente. El motivo
>   de esta decisión fue que si hay muchas visitas a muchas páginas se
>   puede superar la cuota de consultas permitidas a la API.